# HTML5 multi nav tag best practices

Tags: html, nav

I am trying to write a theme with multi menu at the header, should i use multi `nav` tag for each of them? Or wrap them all inside a `nav` tag?

Here is the example [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGEaNm).

`header-a` wrap everything inside `nav` tag.

`header-b` wrap menu and the element that between menu inside `nav`.

`header-c` wrap menu inside `nav` by each.

`header-d` add `nav` tag inside each `bar` to wrap everything inside `bar`.

Which method will be good in this case?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is about semantics.

A `nav` element should wrap items that are part of the same navigation structure.

For example:

```html
<nav id="topNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav id="sideNav">
  <ul>
    <li>Products</li>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Oranges</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Apples</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Pears</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav id="socialNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Facebook</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Twitter</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>LinkedIn</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

See [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp)

> The `<nav>` tag defines a set of navigation links.
>
> Notice that NOT all links of a document should be inside a `<nav>` element. The `<nav>` element is intended only for major block of **navigation links**.
>
> Browsers, such as screen readers for disabled users, can use this element to determine whether to omit the initial rendering of this content.

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem there is an exact answer to this. Rather, the correct answer depends on how you want the semantics of the website to be read.

Try looking at the following sources:

- http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100279/html5-semantics-for-multiple-nav-
  elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100279/html5-semantics-for-multiple-nav-elements)
- http://w3bits.com/css-responsive-nav-menu/

There is information that states that all 4 of your options would be semantically correct. What you need to think about is how you want the navigation to be interpreted: 1) Should it be seen as one main menu? Then you would want `header-a`; 2) Should the menus be seen as groups of related menus? Then any of `header-a`, `header-b` or `header-c` would work.

I know I have not exactly given you an answer to your question but from what I can work out there is no straight forward answer.

Hope this helps in some way.